# Bypass global query filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The global query filter that was introduced in .NET Core 2.0 is pretty handy for soft delete. But if the situation arises, how would I see those soft deleted data? Let's say admin wants to specifically see who has been soft deleted. That means I have to somehow bypass that query filter. Right now I think I can use a `NotMapped` property to indicate whether I'd want to bypass it or not, but I'm looking for best practice.

So currently my idea is, use a `NotMapped` property

```
[NotMapped]
public bool IncludeDeletedFields { get; set; } = false;
```

and use it in the global filter like

```
builder.HasQueryFilter(p => p.IncludeDeletedFields ? p.IsDeleted || !p.IsDeleted : !p.IsDeleted);
```

But is there any better way?

Comment: Use the `IgnoreQueryFilters` option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.ignorequeryfilters?view=efcore-3.0